# Finding patterns within inconsistent data

Tags: dataset, similarities, pattern-recognition

If I have a database full of data sets that I collected from a material sample going through light sensors. Each sample is similar but the data can be inconsistent depending on many factors. I collected data from many samples.

I need to be able to detect if a sample that is put through the sensors is of the same type as all the samples I collected data for (All the samples in the database). If it's a bad replication of the sample (a "counterfeit" if you will) I want to reject the sample.

I need to see how similar the sample being scanned is to the real samples I have data for. But the problem is, even the real samples are inconsistent with respect to each other. So a bad sample could easily look like a good one.

How would I mathematically make sense of the data and find a real consistent pattern that might be "hidden" in all the data I collected with good samples, and not be in the bad samples? I can not collect data that would accurately represent all the bad samples because each bad sample will be different and unknown to me. But I do have some bad sample data, and all bad samples will be within reason somewhat similar to the good samples as far as a general shape of the data goes.

To help narrow down an algorithm:
All data points have values between 0-255.
And each data set has 50 data points.